# Increment Input on Clock Cycle

Tags: circuit-design, sequential-logic

I have an 8-bit input and my goal is to increment the input on each clock cycle. The new value will then be saved into a register to be used to search memory.

Say, for example, the input is currently 2. On the first clock cycle, the input will be saved into the register as a 2. On the second clock cycle, it will become a 3, and then a 4, and so on.

What I've tried is using an 8-bit adder that goes into the register. The issue I'm having is that the clock rises at the same time on both the adder and the register, so the value from the adder is incremented after the register can do anything with the new value. Also, it's not really changing the input value, so in this case it would only ever be a 2 or 3.

[image: My attempt at incrementing the in]

Adder circuit:

[image]

Register:

[image]

Comment: Can you show a circuit schematic (there's a button on the editor toolbar) rather than the model railway?

Comment: You could add a delay for the register clock. Or make the register trigger on the opposite clock edge.

Comment: Register on opposite clock edge works, but it's always going to be stuck in the in and in+1 value options.

Comment: An adder shouldn't need a clock. The adder ***always*** adds 1! It doesn't add the clock! And the register doesn't use this number until the clock changes.

Comment: Exactly, an adder shouldn't need a clock, unless it has a pipeline register on the output; if it does, then *that* is your register and you shouldn't need another register as well.  Of course overall what you are describing has another name: counter

Answer (score 1):

Below is a basic loadable counter; it increments the value of the register, and selects whether to store this or the new *Input* using *Load*.  This all happens ahead of *CLK*, which simply saves the result.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJKyzm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It seems that you want the input to be saved automatically (e.g. on change).  This could be accomplished with another layer of logic that determines the *Load* input.